# Should I add MathJax formatting to posts with plain text math?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing

I personally have noticed a lot of posts were all of the math is written in plain text and have tried my best to fix change them, is this even something that I should even be focusing on, or should I just leave the posts be? I think overall the MathJax formatting looks nicer, is clearer and more legible.

Comment: Don't go over-board over trivial stuff, which uses a couple of numbers: E.g. "7 chairs are arranged in a row.  There are 6 women, and 6 men. How many ways can the 7 chairs be filled, if we require that the number of women seated at any given time is greater than the number of men seated. " $$ $$ I reject edits which go in to turn 7 into $7$, and 6 into $6$.  That's an example of what I consider trivial, in the sense that it does not in any way improve the question.

Comment: See this post  [Am I editing too much?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13689/am-i-editing-too-much), and this post about the frequency of edits [How much bumping is too much](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much),  and this meta post: [How much editing is too much](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/how-much-editing-is-too-much)

Comment: And note this meta question: [Edit rejection: too minor?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13289/edit-rejection-too-minor?rq=1)

Comment: This is also one possible advantage of MathJax which we should keep in mind: *Having the mathematics clearly marked as mathematics (as oppose to "fake" mathematics using other HTML tricks) makes it much easier to properly voice the mathematics for screen readers.* Quoted from an answer here: [Would HTML/Unicode formatting cause troubles?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17496#17543) Some other points raised there are also related. (Although probably not everything which applies to Unicode/HTML applies also to plain text.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the posted comments to avoid only making trivial changes, such as `7` to `$7$` with no other post improvement, but if it contains equations that you're making more legible, then this is a good way to improve the content of this website. Thank you for this important work.

Comment: Not always.  Don't sanction trivial posts. (see my example in a comment below the question.  In such an example, any attempt to put dollar signs around 6, 7 is no improvement to the site; rather, it's a trivial edit seeking only to earn 2 points, if accepted.

Comment: @amWhy It hadn't occurred to me that that might be the way someone acted to gain points. I amended my answer

Comment: I should clarify that I do believe that there are folks who get carried away with mathjax and editing; the think that 2 pt reward/accepted edit may reinforce this.  But very few  get carried away editing solely for the sake of gaining rep.